# setting id of preparedStatement method that belongs to Object from another class

Tags: java, jdbc

So with relation to the previous method. This is my UserDAO, and DaoFactory. The UserDao holds an instance of the daoFactory.

This is my UserDAO:

```
public class UsuariousDAO {

    private static final String SQL_LIST_ALL =
            "SELECT DISTINCT * "
            + "FROM usuarios WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM usuarios_grupos WHERE usuarios_grupos.id_grupo = ? AND usuarios_grupos.id_usuario = usuarios.id_usuario)";


    private static final String SQL_INSERT =
            "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, setor, senha, email, bloquear, admin) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private static final String SQL_UPDATE =
            "UPDATE usuario SET nome = ?, setor = ?, senha = ?, email = ?, bloquear = ?, admin = ? WHERE id_usuario = ?";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE =
            "DELETE FROM usuario WHERE id_usuario = ?";

    private DAOFactory daoFactory;

     UsuariousDAO(DAOFactory daoFactory) {
        this.daoFactory = daoFactory;
    }

     public Usuarious find(Integer id) throws DAOExceptions {
        return find(SQL_LIST_BY_ID_GRUPO, id);
    }
```

I have the following methods in my USERDAO:

```
private Usuarious find(String sql, Object... values) throws DAOExceptions {

                                CODE
}

 public List<Usuarious> list() throws DAOExceptions {

                               CODE
}

 public List<Usuarious> list(Grupos groups) throws DAOExceptions {

                                   CODE
    }


 public void create(Usuarious user) throws IllegalArgumentException, DAOExceptions {

                              CODE
}


public void update(Usuarious user) throws DAOExceptions {
                                  CODE
}



public void save(Usuarious user) throws DAOExceptions {
        if (user.getId_usuario() == null) {
            create(user);
        } else {
            update(user);
        }
    }


public void delete(Usuarious user) throws DAOExceptions {

                    CODE
}

   private static Usuarious mapUser(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        Usuarious user = new Usuarious(rs.getInt("id_usuario"), rs.getString("nome"), rs.getString("setor"),
                rs.getString("senha"), rs.getString("email"), rs.getString("bloquear"), rs.getString("admin"));
        return user;
    }

} //end of class
```

MY DaoFactory class is the following:

```
     public abstract class DAOFactory  {

        private static final String JNDI_ROOT = "java:comp/env/";

         public static DAOFactory getInstance(String name) throws DAOConfigurationException {
            if (name == null) {
                throw new DAOConfigurationException("Database name is null.");
            }

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://200.230.71.12:3306/social";
            String driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String password = "1234cinco";
            String username = "cepein";
            DAOFactory instance;

   if (driverClassName != null) {
            try {
                Class.forName(driverClassName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new DAOConfigurationException(
                    "Driver class '" + driverClassName + "' is missing in classpath.", e);
            }
            instance = new DriverManagerDAOFactory(url, username, password);
        }

        // Else assume URL as DataSource URL and lookup it in the JNDI.
        else {
            DataSource dataSource;
            try {
                dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup(JNDI_ROOT + url);
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                throw new DAOConfigurationException(
                    "DataSource '" + url + "' is missing in JNDI.", e);
            }
            if (username != null) {
                instance = new DataSourceWithLoginDAOFactory(dataSource, username, password);
            } else {
                instance = new DataSourceDAOFactory(dataSource);
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }




  abstract Connection getConnection() throws SQLException;

        // DAO getters --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Returns the User,Grupos, UserGrupos DAO associated with the current DAOFactory.
         * @return The User,Grupos, UserGrupos DAO associated with the current DAOFactory.
         */


          public UsuariousDAO getUserDAO() {
        return new UsuariousDAO(this);
    }

    public GruposDAO getGruposDAO() {
        return new GruposDAO(this);
    }

    public UsuariousGruposDAO getUsuariousGruposDAO() {
        return new UsuariousGruposDAO(this);
    }

}


class DriverManagerDAOFactory extends DAOFactory {
    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    DriverManagerDAOFactory(String url, String username, String password) {
        this.url = url;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
}

/**
 * The DataSource based DAOFactory.
 */
class DataSourceDAOFactory extends DAOFactory {
    private DataSource dataSource;

    DataSourceDAOFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}

/**
 * The DataSource-with-Login based DAOFactory.
 */
class DataSourceWithLoginDAOFactory extends DAOFactory {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    DataSourceWithLoginDAOFactory(DataSource dataSource, String username, String password) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection(username, password);
    }
}
```

Here is my list(Grupos grps):

```
 public List<Usuarious> list(Grupos groups) throws DAOExceptions {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    List<Usuarious> users = new ArrayList<Usuarious>();

    try {
        connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_LIST_ALL);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, groups.getId_grupo());
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            users.add(mapUser(resultSet));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DAOExceptions(e);
    } finally {
        close(connection, preparedStatement, resultSet);
    }

    return users;
}
```

I call the method in my User managed bean here:

```
public List<Usuarious> getListOfUsuarios() throws DAOExceptions {
        List<Usuarious> usuariosList = userDAO.list(grps);
        listOfUsuarios = usuariosList;
        return listOfUsuarios;
    }
```

and in my view, the following:

```
<p:dataTable var="users" value="#{usuariousGruposBean.listOfUsuarios}"
                                 selection="#{users}" selectionMode="single">
                        <p:column headerText="" style="height:0" rendered ="false">
                            <h:outputText value="#{users.id_usuario}"/>
                        </p:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `groups` is null when you call this method, so the problem is in the caller and not here.

`NullPointerException` on `preparedStatement.setInt(1, groups.getId_grupo());` means that either `preparedStatement` or `groups` are null (but we now `preparedStatement` is not).

Comment: I'm not sure it's quite that clear cut. It could be valid for `groups` to be null in the calling method, in which case the `list` method needs to handle that case to avoid the NullPointerException being thrown.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist it's semantically meaningless to call with a `null` parameter (and if it indeed has a meaning, then it should be `list()`); the parameter may be "empty" (i.e. returning `null` on the getters) if that makes sense (in this case, it probably wouldn't). And anyway, here the problem is not wheter it's semantically correct, but that the OP didn't understand that it was null.

Comment: If groups is null, what must I do to have it resolve? Apparently, creating Group groups = new Groups() does not resolve the issue. I am actually trying to pass the id of groups in my application when I select a group from the datatable.

Comment: @ShaunK you have to understand that the problem does not lie in that method, so you have to radically change you question and show where you call the DAO, where you get the Groups object and what's its structure.

Comment: +1 for Groups, also check if you set private .getId_grupo() or just println this int value with static block so you can see what is going on

Comment: getId_grupo() is public. okay will try the latter

Comment: @Viruzzo groups is apparently null. but why would it be null though. Wouldn't creating new group object make it not null

Comment: @ShaunK Yeah, of course, so you must be either doing some other mistake or calling it with null somewhere else. In the code you posted though you never call `list(Grupos groups)`, so I can't help you: find and post that part.

Comment: @Viruzzo okay I just posted my method, and updated the question.

Comment: Where does `grps` come from in `List<Usuarious> usuariosList = userDAO.list(grps);`?

Answer (score 0):

Either groups is null, or the getId_grupo() has Integer as its type, and null as its value. Causing the auto-unboxing to int the throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: It's `setInt(int)` so no to the second option.

Comment: @Viruzzo If you assign a type Integer to a method accepting an int, it will be unboxed, if the Integer is null that will cause an NPE

Comment: @MarkRotteveel true, but only in Java 5+. And no, that's not an automatic assumption. I would agree though that it's a very annoying behaviour to have autounboxing throw NullPointerException, and it can be very unpredictable.

Comment: @Viruzzo As Java 5 has been out for 7+ years I no longer think about Java 1.4 or earlier, unless I really have to :) I do agree that the NPE is annoying, but it is preferable over an implicit conversion to zero, as that could be more insidious.